# Calendar application which can also track habits for android

Tags: android, calendar

I am looking for a calendar application which can also track habits for android which has the below features:

1. Reminders on events that I setup
2. Create repeatable events which I can simply check or cross.
3. Preferably track holidays
4. Preferably integrate with my google account

I know of applications which do either 1 or 2, but not both, and I don't want to install, multiple applications for that

EDIT:
Explanation for #2: Let's say I want to add running as a repeatable event which can potentially happen once per day. But say this week, I ran only on Monday, and Friday, so I would like to check Running on Monday and Friday. The main difference between a regular event (which can be repeated on a fixed schedule) and a repeatable event is that the repeatable event does not necessarily happen every "period", but let's the user specify if it happened or not. It is more like tracking a habit

Comment: Thanks! Now I see why you couldn't find an app supporting 1+2 (I misunderstood 2). Tough one then, never heard of such (and you might know, I'm quite deep into what apps do exist if you do check [my app lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php) – be welcome to check the [calendar section](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_general), but I doubt any calendar has that feature).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for checking. I am really hoping someone knows about such an application and I don't end up rolling my own